# UPDATE MySQL with 'onclick' button command in Django Project

Tags: javascript, python, html, mysql, django

I am extremely new to django and web dev on the whole, so please bear with me.

I have created a simple site with a MySQL backend for my local football team and want to create a page to update the score of a game (stored on a table)  simply by clicking a button (increment the current score by + 1).
I have no doubt in my mind that this is super simple, but after WEEKS of trawling through similar posts, nothing seemed to work for me (nothing that I could understand at least).

I have a template that that creates a button that contains the ID for the record that needs to be updated:

```
<a href="{% url livegame_update %}?value={{stat.id}}?updatetype=goals" class="btn btn-success" role="button" onclick="alert({{stat.id}})" id={{stat.id}}>Goal</a>
```

This points to this URL:

```
url(r'^livegame_update', 'steelers_fc.players.views.livegame_update', name='livegame_update'),
```

Which in turn executes this function the Views;

```
def livegame_update(request):
StatID = request.GET.get('value','1')
StatType = request.GET.get('updatetype','1')
SQL = "update players_statistics set " + StatType + " = " + StatType + " + 1 where id = " + StatID + ";"
#stat_edit = statistics.objects.get(id=StatID)
#stat_edit.goals = stat_edit.goals + 1
#stat_edit.save() # save object

cursor = connection.cursor ()
cursor.execute (SQL)
connection.commit()
cursor.close ()
connection.close ()

return render_to_response
```

Ultimately, the SQL above would end up being:
 "*update players_statistics set goals = goals + 1 where id = 99*"

I have tried several things:

- Execute RAW SQL (as per this example)
- Update Django Model (as per the commented out section)
- Executed an external .py script (which works perfectly well from a Bash Comamnd)
- Looked at using 'forms'..but never really understood.

Ultimately, I feel the issue is around the URL and the passing of parameters between the request and the view?!?!

Any help would be greatly appreciated and some simple examples would be amazing.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know what sql injection is?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Yep, absolutely. But this really isn't anything important. Just a training session for me while creating something semi-useful for some friends :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... First of all I do not understand why are you creating cursors and stuff.

I`ll try to help you out here in most easy way I can imagine.

**STEP 1 (if you do not have model)**

Create model

```
class Match(models.Model):
    goals = models.IntegerField(default=)
    # Add as many fields as you need, eg. Teams / Scorer / and other stuff

    def __str___(self):
    return self.goals
```

**STEP 2 - urls.py / you have, but some parts are missing**

```
url(r'^livegame_update/(?P<match_id>[\d]+)/$', 'steelers_fc.players.views.livegame_update', name='livegame_update'),
```

Explanation: As you can see your url now takes match_id as parameter passed to your view. The part with **[\d]+** - says it has to be a number, plus means unlimited number.

**STEP 3 - Your view (update)**

```
def livegame_update(request, match_id):
    try:
        match = Match.objects.get(id=match_id)
    except Match.DoesNotExist():
        return render(request, 'your_template.html', {'error': 'match with given id dosnt exist})
    match.goals += 1
    match.save()

    return render(request, 'your_template.html', {'msg': 'incremented score'})
```

so simply what this does is: Find me a Match object with id given in parameter (**match_id**). If it is not found, return to your template, and pass a dict with an error. If it exists increment your **goals** field by one. Then save your object. Finally return to your template with buttons and stuff.

Is it clear ? Do you need to explain anything in above code ?

Comment: Hi, that is perfectly clear. Thank you for the great explanation.
I just have one question re: passing the 'match_id' to the URL.
My button now looks like this: <a href="{% url livegame_update %} {{stat.id}}" class="btn btn-success" role="button" onclick="alert({{stat.id}})" id={{stat.id}}>Goal</a>  
With {{stat.id}} being the match_id.
Does that make sense??

Comment: Yes, you have to pass to your url an ID of your object, which you want to update.

Comment: Hi Sebb. At the risk of pushing stupidness to a whole new level...can you please help with the html syntax I need for the href....as I am still getting nowhere with updating the table.
Currently, I am creating the link like this: href="{% url livegame_update %}?match_id={{stat.id}}".
Thanks

Comment: at first just try to make it work like this

`<a href="/livegame_update/{{stat.id}}/">GOAL </a>`